# Pythonをタスクスケジューラで起動したときのエラーについて

Tags: python, windows, python3, exception

Windows10環境のタスクスケジューラよりPythonを起動し、win32comを利用してOutlookからメールを送信しようとしていたのですが、以下のエラーが発生してしまいメールが送信できずに困っております。

どなたか回避策等ご存知でしたらご教示願えますでしょうか。
※ VSCode上からの実行では問題なく送信できています。。。

```
2018-04-25 22:06:12,455 - logExample - ERROR - Error do something: (-2146959355, 'サーバーの実行に失敗しました', None, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3.6.5\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 89, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, '操作を利用できません', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\projects\Pythons\operation_tools\mainExecute.py", line 263, in <module> 
    application = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3.6.5\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3.6.5\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3.6.5\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2146959355, 'サーバーの実行に失敗しました', None, None)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Office のサーバーサイド オートメーションについて](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)にて

> マイクロソフトは、現在のところ、無人の非対話型クライアント アプリケーションまたはコンポーネント (ASP、ASP.NET、DCOM、および NT サービスを含む) からの Microsoft Office アプリケーションのオートメーションに関して、推奨もサポートも行っていません。それは、このような環境で Office を実行した場合、Office で不安定な動作やデッドロックが発生する可能性があるためです。

と説明されています。タスクスケジューラではOutlookを実行できない前提で検討されることをお勧めします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！
そうだったのですね。。。気が付きませんでした。
Outlook起動できないを前提に検討し直したいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

サーバー環境でPythonから Excel, Word, PowerPoint を利用したい場合は、openpyxl, pydoc, pyppt 等のライブラリーを使って直接ファイルを操作するようにします。また、メールクライアントであれば、Pythonの標準ライブラリーにある`smtplib`と`email`を使って簡単に作ることが可能です。これでかなりのことは対応できると思います。

それで対応ができないような場合は、Google の Gmail, Sheets, Documents, Slides, Calenderの方を使うようにします。こちらは、Microsoft Officeと違ってAPIがあるのでサーバー環境からでも利用可能です。