# ログではpythonからメール送信(Outlook)できているが実際には送信されていない

Tags: python

よろしくお願いします

## やりたいこと

- pythonからメール送信したい
- プログラムはWindowsのタスクスケジューラに設定して定期的に実行したい

## 困っていること

- 実行後にログを見るとメール送信済みになっているが、実際には送信されていない
- 手動で実行するとうまくいく

## 環境

- Python 3.8.1
- メール送信用にwin32comを使用

## 試してみたこと

- sleepを入れてみたが効果なし

タスクスケジューラに鍵があるのでしょうか？

Comment: Python プログラムの中身や、実行時のログにどんなメッセージが出ていたか (何をもって "送信済み" と判断したか) などの情報が無いと回答が付きづらいかもしれません。 / 質問は後からでも [edit] できるので、必要に応じて見直してみてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
Python側ではなく、タスクスケジューラ側（マイクロソフト側）の問題でした。
サーバー環境でメール送信するにはOutlookを利用するよりPythonの標準ライブラリを利用した方が良いという回答を下記で見つけました。
`smtplib`と`email`で実装し、やりたいことができるようになりました。

[Pythonをタスクスケジューラで起動したときのエラーについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43549/python%E3%82%92%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B1%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A9%E3%81%A7%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6?rq=1)